# onActivityResult from service to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity which starts my service. After it starts, the service should send data in a fragment. On broad gullies shows that service was started, has made operations, but the fragment has not given out broad gullies showing that it has obtained data. How can I make such a chain activity-> service-> a fragment?

main.java (Activity)

```
kill = new Intent(this, timer.class);

        pi = createPendingResult(TASK1_CODE, kill, 0);

        intent = new Intent(this, timer.class).putExtra(PARAM_TIME, 7)
                .putExtra(PARAM_PINTENT, pi);

        startService(intent);

        pi = createPendingResult(TASK2_CODE, kill, 0);
        intent = new Intent(this, timer.class).putExtra(PARAM_TIME, 4)
                .putExtra(PARAM_PINTENT, pi);
        startService(intent);

        pi = createPendingResult(TASK3_CODE, kill, 0);
        intent = new Intent(this, timer.class).putExtra(PARAM_TIME, 6)
                .putExtra(PARAM_PINTENT, pi);
        startService(intent);
```

timer.java (Service)

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyService onStartCommand");
        int time = intent.getIntExtra(user_rassp.PARAM_TIME, 1);
        PendingIntent pi = intent.getParcelableExtra(user_rassp.PARAM_PINTENT);

    MyRun mr = new MyRun(time, startId, pi);
    es.execute(mr);
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

class MyRun implements Runnable {

    int time;
    int startId;
    PendingIntent pi;

    public MyRun(int time, int startId, PendingIntent pi) {
        this.time = time;
        this.startId = startId;
        this.pi = pi;
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyRun#" + startId + " create");
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyRun#" + startId + " start, time = " + time);
        try {

            pi.send(user_rassp.STATUS_START);

            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(time);


            Intent intent = new Intent().putExtra(user_rassp.PARAM_RESULT, time * 100);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "конец");
            pi.send(timer.this, user_rassp.STATUS_FINISH, intent);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stop();
    }

    void stop() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyRun#" + startId + " end, stopSelfResult("
                + startId + ") = " + stopSelfResult(startId));
    }
}
```

user_rasp.java (fragment)

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "requestCode = " + requestCode + ", resultCode = "
            + resultCode);

    // Ловим сообщения о старте задач
    if (resultCode == STATUS_START) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case TASK1_CODE:
                Log.d("task1","start");
                break;
            case TASK2_CODE:
                Log.d("task1", "start");
                break;
            case TASK3_CODE:
                Log.d("task1", "start");
                break;
        }
    }

    // Ловим сообщения об окончании задач
    if (resultCode == STATUS_FINISH) {
        int result = data.getIntExtra(PARAM_RESULT, 0);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case TASK1_CODE:
                Log.d("Task1", "finish, result = " + result);
                break;
            case TASK2_CODE:
                Log.d("Task2", "finish, result = " + result);
                break;
            case TASK3_CODE:
                Log.d("Task3", "finish, result = " + result);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is a broad gully ? logs ?

Comment: Read about "bound services"

Comment: You will receive the result in the `Activity`, not `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

Register a BroadCastReceiver in Fragment. You will need to use an action for it.

From Service send broadcastMessage with above Intent Action. You can pass data via Intent extras